# E-Mail on iPad and E-Mail on Computer not connected

Tags: ios, ipad, email

I have my Hotmail account setup on my iPad and everything is working. However whenever I go to my computer and login to my Hotmail account all messages are unread even though I read them on my iPad. This never happened before. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

Hotmail uses the [POP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_Office_Protocol) protocol. This protocol only allows to download mails from the server. Therefore it does not sync mail for example to mark them as read.

If you want to fix this you have to configure your Hotmail account to uses the [IMAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Message_Access_Protocol) protocol which allows the synchronising... But this is really tricky to do.  :

1. If it's not done : Migrate your **Hotmail** account to **Outlook.com**
2. On the iDevice : Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendar > Other
3. *Add Mail account*
4. Add a fake mail account (if iOS detecte a @hotmail.com, @live.com or @outlook.com it will suppose it is POP only)
5. You'll get an error (normal, you added a fake account)
6. After this you'll have 2 tabs : IMAP and POP, file the IMAP tab with the following infos :

   - Incoming mail server :

     - Host Name : imap-mail.outlook.com
     - Port : 993
     - SSL : yes
   - Serveur sortant :

     - Host name : smtp-mail.outlook.com
     - Port : 587
     - TLS : yes